# showing multiple regions for holidays in Calendar Version 7.0 (1841.1)

Tags: calendar

Can you choose more than one region to show holidays in calendar Version 7.0 (1841.1)

Comment: What is a region for you? A timezone?

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many as you like - http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/